# display multiple annotations on mapview

Tags: arrays, swift, annotations, mapkit

I've been looking around on stackoverflow for a solution but I haven't yet successfully implemented it. If someone can give me some tips on where the problem lies, thank you so much. Here is what I have so far

Here is location class

```
class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}
```

Method to display all annotations.

```
func displayAllEventsPins() {
    for event in events {
        let address = event.location
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address!, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let eventlat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let eventlong = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = event.name
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: eventlat!, longitude: eventlong!)
                self.locations.append(Location(title: annotation.title!, coordinate: annotation.coordinate))
                    for location in self.locations {
                    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
                    pin.title = location.title
                    pin.coordinate = location.coordinate
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**Edited**: The problem here is that annotations doesnt show up on mapview. I can only see the currentlocation pin and nothing else.

**Edited**: This is the call i used to drop user current location pin.

```
extension Search : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestLocation()

    }
}

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //MARK: remove previous current pin for user location
    mapView.removeAnnotation(newPin)

    let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    self.currentLocation = location
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.03, 0.03))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    newPin.coordinate = location.coordinate
    mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)
}
}
```

Here is the code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK:  Request Current Location
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()
   displayAllEventsPins()
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: annotations doesnt show on mapview. I can only view current location. I'm not sure if I implemented the displayalleventspins correctly. The logic made sense in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

By the way, looping through your locations whilst in the events loop is just going to add duplicates of the same pin, which will be very bad on memory and it's not a good thing to do.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var events = Array<Event>()

    var locations = Array<Location>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        // This closure gets called once for every event in your database
        getEvents { (event, pin) in

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            if event != nil && pin != nil {

                print(event!)

                self.locations.append(pin!)

                self.events.append(event!)

            } else {

                print("Failed to get event.")
            }
        }
    }

    func getEvents(results: @escaping (_ event: Event?, _ pin:Location?)->()) {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Events")

        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let value = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,String> else { return }

            guard let name = value["eventName"],
            let location = value["location"],
            let attending = value["attendance"],
            let dateTime = value["dateTime"],
            let addedByUser = value["addedByUser"] else { return }

            self.getEventPlacemark(address: location, results: { (placemark) in

                if let placemark = placemark {

                    let pin = Location(title: name, coordinate: placemark.coordinate)

                    var distance: Double = -1 // If user location is not avalible, this will stay at -1

                    if let currentLocation = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate {

                        distance = pin.coordinate.distance(to: currentLocation)
                    }

                    let event = Event(id: snapshot.key, name: name, location: location, dateTime: dateTime, addedByUser: addedByUser, attending: attending, distance: distance)

                    results(event, pin)

                    return
                }
            })
        })
    }

    func getEventPlacemark(address:String, results: @escaping (_ placemark: MKPlacemark?)->()){

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

                results(nil)
            }

            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {

                results(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
            }
        }
    }

    func displayAllEvents(){

        self.map.addAnnotations(self.locations)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if let userLocation = annotation as? MKUserLocation {

            let view = (mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "userLocationPin") as? MKPinAnnotationView) ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: userLocation, reuseIdentifier: "userLocationPin")

            view.pinTintColor = .purple

            view.canShowCallout = true

            return view
        }

        if let pin = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {

            let view = (mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView) ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: pin, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

            view.pinTintColor = .red

            view.canShowCallout = true

            return view
        }

        return nil
    }
}

class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var title: String?

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        self.title = title

        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}


struct Event {

    var name: String

    var location: String
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    func distance(to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {

        return MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPointForCoordinate(self), MKMapPointForCoordinate(to))
    }
}
```

If you are going to implement my code above, you'll need to remove your code from

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

because you don't need to add the pin manually anymore.

Can you try putting this in your view did load function and not have anything else run. This should put a pin to the west of Africa.

> Something to notice, if the coordinate is
>   CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), the pin appears 
>   right down at Antartica on the date line, which is the bottom right of
>   the map. So if for some reason your coordinate is the default 0,0,
>   your pins might by sitting there.

```
let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

pin.title = "Null Island"

pin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.000001, 0.000001)

self.map.addAnnotation(pin)
```

This could possibly be where your pins are.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the looping advice. I followed your code and nothing showed up. I put the function in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: I've added all my code that makes it work for me. If you are still having trouble, you'll need to add more code to your question, preferably the whole ViewController, so I can see if you have done something wrong.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Do you think it might be because of the currentLocation method? Everything else in the code has nothing to do with the mapView. I updated the question to include the portion of the drop currentlocation pin.

Comment: Are you trying to show the user's location as a pin instead of the pulsing blue circle?

Comment: yes initially. However, if that interferes with the locations pins, I wouldn't mind changing it. Is that the reason that the code doesnt show all the other pins?

Comment: That wouldn't stop the pins from showing, it's just that there is a more efficient way of doing it. I've updated my code above. I suggest that you at least try my method just in case it fixes you problem.  From the additional code that you have added, I can't seem to find any problem. Are you able to upload your whole class so I can check that you haven't done something else wrong?

Comment: I managed to get the blue dot as user current location. But the event pins still don't show up. Here is the link to my code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kken3cy3ri18fdv/Search.swift?dl=0

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with you code, although I cannot test it since I don't have the whole project. In your observeEvents function, are you actually getting any events? Because I've created a test database based on your code, and mine works fine, so I was wondering whether any events are being added to your events array.

Comment: The observeEvents function is called properly, I managed to populate the tableview with the events and its property. This is very strange since I can't seem to understand why the locations pins are not being displayed. Can you explain the "return nil" at the end for the mapview func. Shouldn't it return the view instead.

Comment: The map view delegate isn't required to show pins. It only needs to be connected if you are using a delegate method. The one I have above is optional.

Comment: sorry I just edited my comment above. I'm a little confused with the " return nil" at the end of the mapview func.

Comment: That just sets the default view for that annotation type. With the user location and the point annotation we a customising it, so we are returning a new view.

Comment: I still can't seem to figure this out and It's driving my nuts! I still accepted your answer though It hasn't worked out for me. Here are the few things I have checked off :
_ observeEvents works
_ currentlocation pin portion in mapview func works

* the only thing left that i suspect is that the beginning of the "for loop" which "address" return nil. However, that would mean the observeEvents method should also be not working.

Comment: Is that the 'let address = event.location' that is nil.

Comment: Have you tried my getEvents function, because when it comes to displayAllEvents its just adds all the pins to the map, instead of geocoding then again? Also, the way I have shown above only has the event run through the geocoder once, whereas yours will go through multiple times, which will use more data and delay the user.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test out the getEvents method. But i think the for loop is the problem for me. I will put in a print message to see if the code is executed properly.